# BigDecimal.setScale() doesn't return the correct result

Tags: java

I'm trying to round up the Digdecimal by using RoundingMode, but in my test, bd is still 6.45607,   why setScale() doesn't work?

```
String precision = "2";

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("6.45607");


if(bd != null) {
   bd.setScale(Integer.parseInt(precision), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}

System.out.println("result  " + bd);
```

Comment: `setScale` returns a new BigDecimal. You're ignoring the return value.

Comment: It does return the correct result.  You just aren't storing the returned result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) for `setScale`.

> Note that since BigDecimal objects are immutable, calls of this method do not result in the original object being modified, contrary to the usual convention of having methods named setX mutate field X. Instead, setScale returns an object with the proper scale; the returned object may or may not be newly allocated.